# Save history products in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, triggers

I want to write a method to save the history of changes in the table. I have three tables (products, articles and categories). When a user makes a change, for example in the product name. I want to display a message at the product, example: **User *Jack* change the *name* of product with "ball" on the "ball2016."**
I came up with that I created new pivot table "history_products" wherein the columns will: "user_id", "products_id", "created_at" and "updated_at". This table will be connected with table products. I want to used this **trigger**. You think it's a good idea or in a Laravel can do it in an easier way??

Comment: you can use  [laravel events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/events) in this situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a good source/library is `revisionable`, the following:
[VentureCraft/revisionable](https://github.com/VentureCraft/revisionable)